# An issue with creating an onClick effect for individual buttons using react state

Tags: reactjs, button, onclick, state

So I'm pretty new to React and web development in general (fresh from a bootcamp) so my questions can come off as quite stupid. I've got a problem styling buttons after they're clicked on using React state.

All of them updated at once after I click on one of them and I've been banging my head against the wall after that.

```
class Foundations extends Component {

state = {
    clicked: false
}

handleClickFunds = () => {
    this.setState({
        clicked: true
    })
}

handleClickOrgs = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        clicked: !prevState.clicked
    }));
}

handleClickLocals = () => {
    this.setState({
        clicked: true
    });
}

render() {

    const Button = styled.button`
        background: white;
        outline: none;
        appearance: none;
        border: none;
        width: 150px;
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 0 10px;
        font-size: 1em;
        border: ${props => props.clicked ? '1px solid black' : 'none'};
        border-radius: 3px;
    `;

 return (
                <Buttons>
                    <Button clicked={this.state.clicked} onClick={this.handleClickFunds}>Fundacjom</Button>
                    <Button clicked={this.state.clicked} onClick={this.handleClickOrgs}>Organizacjom</Button>
                    <Button clicked={this.state.clicked} onClick={this.handleClickLocals}>Lokalnym zbiórkom</Button>
                </Buttons>
```

I need to style them upon click and delete styles from previously clicked buttons. Any advice? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the same state variable to tell whether your buttons have been clicked or not. So, when you click one of them, the others are listening to the same `clicked` state variable.

Try using a different state variable for each one, like this:

```
state = {
    fundsClicked: false,
    orgsClicked: false,
    localsClicked: false,
}

... 

<Button clicked={this.state.fundsClicked} onClick={this.handleClickFunds}>Fundacjom</Button>
<Button clicked={this.state.orgsClicked} onClick={this.handleClickOrgs}>Organizacjom</Button>
<Button clicked={this.state.localsClicked} onClick={this.handleClickLocals}>Lokalnym zbiórkom</Button>
```

Then, make sure to update the correct state variable inside your click handlers.